# error: redeclaration of ‘y2’ with no linkage

Tags: c, linkage, redeclaration

I am tring to create a program that recieves integer values and converts them into 2's complement integers using atoi, and determines what type of turn was made. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int turn(int turn, int a1, int b1, int a2, int b2, int a3, int b3){
;
  turn = ((a1 * b1 + b1 * a3 + a2 * a3) - (b2 * a3 + a1 * b3 + a2 * b1));
  printf("\n value = %d \n", turn);

  return(turn);
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

  int x1, y2, x2, y2, x3, y3, turn;

  x1 = atoi(argv[1]);
  y1 = atoi(argv[2]);
  x2 = atoi(argv[3]);
  y2 = atoi(argv[4]);
  x3 = atoi(argv[5]);
  y3 = atoi(argv[6]);

  turn = turn(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);

  if(turn == 0) printf("\n Straight \n");
  if(turn < 0) printf("\n Right Turn \n");
  if(turn > 0) printf("\n Left Turn \n");

  return 0 ;

}
```

And my errors:

```
make -k p3
cc     p3.c   -o p3
p3.c: In function ‘main’:
p3.c:29:19: error: redeclaration of ‘y2’ with no linkage
p3.c:29:11: note: previous declaration of ‘y2’ was here
p3.c:32:3: error: ‘y1’ undeclared (first use in this function)
p3.c:32:3: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
p3.c:38:14: error: called object ‘turn’ is not a function
make: *** [p3] Error 1
```

Compilation exited abnormally with code 2 at Sun Sep 22 20:07:02"

I am wondering the cause of this error.

Thanks,

Comment: Using "turn" for both a function name and an argument name is fishy at best. Using that argument as a local variable is even less wholesome.  You force the caller to turn() to proved a first argument that isn't used either to pass or return a value, just so you don't have to declare a local variable to hold the result before returning it.  I suggest that you take "turn" out of the argument list, and declare a local variable instead, preferably with a different name.

Comment: it's strange that the turn function compiles. turn may be a function pointer in that and cause problem with assigning to lvalue. The outside turn also creates an error in main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors that you are getting are exactly what the message is telling you.

- You are declaring your variable `y2` twice
- You did not declare `y1` anywhere
- You can't have two members with the same name like this. You have a `turn` variable which has the same name as your `turn` function.

Comment: thanks.. accidentally declared y2 twice instead of y2 and y1.

Answer (score 1):

---

Before main() in Declaration of int Turn(); u have something like this int Turn(){;
which should be either { or ;.

In Main() you declared Y2 twice and one of which should be Y1.

NOTE:AFTER OPENING OF{ THERE CAN'T BE ; IN YOUR CODE IT IS THERE

---